# How do you store and count a score for a math quiz in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite new to VB and am doing a small school project, I am making a math quiz that will as the user random math questions and if they get the question correct then their score will increase by 1, i do not know how to count the score though. This is the code i have so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Ans As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateProblem()
        CreateScore()
    End Sub

    Sub CreateProblem()
        Dim Generator As New Random
        Dim Num1 As Integer = Generator.Next(15, 20)
        Dim Num2 As Integer = Generator.Next(0, 15)
        Dim Show As String = ""
        Dim SumType As Integer = Generator.Next(1, 3)
        If SumType = 1 Then 
            Show = Num1 & "+" & Num2 & "= ?"
            Ans = Num1 + Num2
        ElseIf SumType = 2 Then 
            Show = Num1 & "-" & Num2 & "= ?"
            Ans = Num1 - Num2
        ElseIf SumType = 3 Then
            Show = Num1 & "*" & Num2 & "= ?"
            Ans = Num1 * Num2
        End If
        Label4.Text = Show


    End Sub
    Sub CreateScore()
        Dim Score As Integer
        If Ans = Val(txtAnswer.Text) Then 
            Score = Score + 1 
        End If
        If Score >= 10 Then 
            MsgBox("Well Done! You have completed the quiz!")
        End If
        lblScore.Text = Score 
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        Call CreateProblem()
        txtAnswer.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtAnswer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAnswer.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCheck_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
        If Val(txtAnswer.Text) = Ans Then 
            MsgBox("Correct")
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect") 
        End If
        Call CreateScore()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the line

```
Dim Score As Integer
```

at the global level has you have for the Ans and Num variables.
In this way the value stored in this variable is available between calls to your CreateScore method

Of course, now you have another problem. You need a way to RESET this value when your user starts a new test. Probably you should add a button the clear that value and sets it to zero

Here the relevant documentation about [Variable declaration in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835.aspx)

Comment: Okay thanks man, I'll probably have another problem tomorrow :D